# Failed building wheel for cx_Freeze error while building cx_Freeze

Tags: python, pip, cx-freeze

I was trying to install `cx_Freeze` with pip and got this error:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for cx_Freeze
Failed to build cx_Freeze
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cx_Freeze, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried to re-install it with "no cache" mode enabled but it didn't help.

Comment: Please show the entire text of the error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

stype 1

pip install cx_logging

stype 2

pip install cx_Freeze

Comment: try to install cx_logging before cx_freeze

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).